# Cron job every day from 8AM to 8PM at 20 minutes interval

Tags: ruby, cron, whenever, cron-task, whenever-capistrano

How to run `cron job` every day from `8:00 AM` to `8:00 PM` at 20 minutes interval eg cron job  should start at `8:00 AM` every day, then run at `8:20 AM` then `8:40 AM` then `9:00 AM` up to `8:00 PM`. Thanks.

**EDIT:** How to Implement it with ruby `whenever` gem.

Answer (score 9):

Just use two cronjobs:

```
*/20 8-19 * * * /your/script
0 20 * * * /your/script
```

That is:

- one to run every 20 minutes from 8 to 19 hours
- one to run at 20.00.

As a reminder, this is the format for a cronjob:

```
 +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
 |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```